# Asp.Net Core MVC + Windows Authentication + IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

У меня есть приложение ASP.NET Core MVC с аутентификацией Windows. Я опубликовал его на сервере IIS в локальной сети нашей компании.

Все работает нормально, все пользователи входят в систему со своими правами. Но каждый раз, когда они открывают браузер, им нужно ввести свои учетные данные. Каждый раз мы видим окно для ввода имени пользователя и пароля.

Как сделать вход в систему автоматическим?

Я добавил это в Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
…
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

//custom authorization
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy("Operator", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new CheckADGroupRequirement(Configuration["RolesConfig:Operator"], Configuration["RolesConfig:Manager"])));
   options.AddPolicy("Manager", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new CheckADGroupRequirement(Configuration["RolesConfig:Manager"])));
});

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CheckADGroupHandler>();
//custom authorization

…
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
…
app.UseAuthentication();
…
}
```

В IIS я выставил Enabled только Windows Authentication.

Единственное решение, которое я нашел это выставить 'Automatic logon with current user and password' в Internet Options, но это не лучшее решение.